# Luabind-like syntax (index operator)

Tags: c++, c++11, lua, luabind

Currently im experimenting with the Luabind-Library and I stumbled upon its calling syntax. It behaves and works like expected, but somehow I can not understand why or how it does.
The code in question is following:

```
Class Animation
{
    std::vector frames;
public:
    Animation(){}
    ~Animation(){}
    addFrame(const Texture2D *in_image);
};

//Somewhere else
luabind::module(LuaState)
[
 luabind::class_("Animation")    // < "Animation" how we want to name the Class in the Lua runtime
 .def(luabind::constructor<>())             // < Binds the empty constructor
 .def("addFrame", &Animation::addFrame)     // < Binds the &Animation::addFrame method to lua with the name "addFrame"
];
```

To be more specific, I don't understand what's happening in the square brackets. Why does this work? I tried to read trough the source code of Luabind, sadly without success. I also tried to reconstruct this behaviour, which was also unsuccessful.
So, am I missing something very obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `luabind::module` is a function, and it returns type `luabind::module_`, which has an overloaded `[]` operator taking an argument of type `luabind::scope`.
- `luabind::class_` is a class and it has a constructor that takes type `const char*` and a member function `def` which returns `class_&` so calls to `def` can be chained.
- `luabind::class_` is derived from a class called `luabind::detail::class_base`, which is derived from `luabind::scope`, so the final `class_` returned can be converted to `scope` and passed as an argument to `luabind::module_::operator[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed!